# Pagination required to limit my .csv file result on my PHP Page

Tags: php, csv

In my csv file ("food.csv"), the data is stored in the order of -ITEM,DESC,QTY,RATE,TYPE.  When I use the array to find the item code, the entire results are coming in one page.  What I need is the result should be limited to 5 case per page  along with " NEXT /BACK". Can any body help me please? other wise suggest any other option please.  The PHP file is given below.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("food.csv","r")or die("file dont exist");
$output = '  ';
while (!feof($handle )){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",");
        if($data[0] ==100){
        $output .= sprintf( "<b>Fruit Name: %s.   </b><br>",  $data[1]);
        $output .= sprintf( "Quantity Avaliable:  %d  Kgs @ %d USD each.   <br>",  $data[2], $data[3]);
        $output .= sprintf( "Item code:  %d (Stock:  %s) <br><hr><br>", $data[4],$dara[0]);   
        }
}
echo $output;
fclose($handle);
?>
```

The entire results are coming ( 12 cases) in a single page like:

> Fruit Name:  MANGO
>   Quantity Available: 10  Kgs @  500 USD each. 
>   Item code:  100  (Stock:  OLD)
>
> Fruit Name:  APPALE
>   Quantity Available: 12 Kgs @  300 USD each. 
>   Item code:  100  (Stock:  NEW)
>
> Fruit Name:  MANGO
>   Quantity Available: 5 Kgs @  650 USD each. 
>   Item code:  100  (Stock:  NEW)

Comment: I think that you will need to load the entire file into memory to get a count of the number of rows. That or you will need to always go through the entire file.

Comment: get a count of records , use LIMIT and implement back and next button

Comment: @CodingAnt how do you use `LIMIT` on a csv file

Comment: @gwillie OOPS I didnt see csv , I missed out , Sorry

Comment: You need proper array pagination, the one like Zend Framework 2 has. Don't even try to implement your own array pagination as its much more complex that MySQL pagination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want to have a variable that stands for the page, and then calculate beginning and ending values. Then only output the date if it is between those ranges. Please excuse the code, I am a little rusty with PHP.

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("food.csv","r")or die("file dont exist");
$output = '  ';
$numPerPage = 5;
$page = $_GET['page'];
$count = 0;
$start = $page * $numPerPage;
$end = ($page + 1) * $numPerPage;
while (!feof($handle )){
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",");
        if($data[0] ==100 && $count < $end && $count >= $start){
        $output .= sprintf( "<b>Fruit Name: %s.   </b><br>",  $data[1]);
        $output .= sprintf( "Quantity Avaliable:  %d  Kgs @ %d USD each.   <br>",  $data[2], $data[3]);
        $output .= sprintf( "Item code:  %d (Stock:  %s) <br><hr><br>", $data[4],$data[0]);

        if($count == $numPerPage) {
            if($page != 0) {
                $output .= '<a href="?page="' . ($page - 1) . '">BACK</a> ';
            }
            if(!feof($handle)) {
                $output .= ' <a href="?page="' . ($page + 1) . '">NEXT</a>';
            }
        }

        $count++
        }
}
echo $output;
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Can't test this now. Let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: **It is showing:**                                                    The website encountered an error while retrieving http://www.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: Looks like there was a typo in your original code. I have will edit my post to fix it. It looks like one of your `$data[]` terms was typed wrong. Not sure if that was the entire problem though.

Comment: My earlier code mentioned above is working fine but it gives the results of more than 12 cases in a single page.  After modifying the code with your suggestion, it is showing configured incorrectly.  Kindly check the code once again please.

Comment: I don't think `$dara[0]` was going to get you anything that you wanted. I will have to double check the code later. It would be helpful if you can post at least some of the csv file so I have something to run it against when I have a chance to test it.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to skip to the lines you need

```
$fh = fopen('food.csv', 'r');
while ((feof($fh) === false) ){
  $i=1;
  $start = 5;
  $end = 10;
  while ((feof($fh) === false) && $i > $start && $i < $end){
    fgets($fh);
    $i++;
  }
  $line = fgets($fh);
  echo $line;
}
fclose($fh);
```

Not tested but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

    if ( ! empty($_FILES['file']['name']) ) {
        $f = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'r');

        $head = fgetcsv($f,0,',','"');
        $num_per_page = 50;

        $out = array(1 => '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><tr><th>'. join('</th><th>',$head) .'</th></tr>');
        $k = count($out);

        $i = 0;
        $p = 1;
        $z = -1;
        while( $arr = fgetcsv($f,0,',','"') ) {
            $arr = array_pad($arr,$k,'');
            if ( $i >= $num_per_page ) {
                $i = 0;
                $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'</table>';
                $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'<div style="text-align: right;">';
                if ( $p > 1 ) {
                    $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'<a href="?p='. ($p -1 ) .'">&lt; Previous</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                }
                $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'<a href="?p='. ($p +1 ) .'">Next &gt;</a>';
                $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'</div>';

                $p++;
                $out[$p] = '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"><tr><th>'. join('</th><th>',$head) .'</th></tr>';
            }
            $z *= -1;
            $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'<tr '. ( $z > 0 ? 'class="odd"' : '' ) .'><td>'. join('</td><td>',$arr) .'</td></tr>';
            $i++;
        }
        if ( $i > 0 ) {
            $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'</table>';
        }
        if ( $p > 1 ) {
            $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'<div style="text-align: right;">';
            $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'<a href="?p='. ($p -1 ) .'">&lt; Previous</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
            $out[$p] = $out[$p] .'</div>';
        }

        echo '<pre>'. htmlspecialchars('<?php' ."\n"
            .'$arr = '. var_export($out,true) .'; $p = 1; if ( ! empty($_GET[\'p\']) ) $p = intval($_GET[\'p\']); if ( ! array_key_exists($p,$arr) ) $p = 1; echo $arr[$p];'
            . "\n". '?>'
        );

    } else {
?>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        CSV File<input type="file" name="file" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
<?php
    }

?>
```